# Replace method in Python and \

Tags: python, string, replace

I am using replace string method in Python and I am finding something that I cannot understand.

Changing the way that a folder is written in python to windows notation, I find that replace method will change this double / for a double \ instead of just one \ as intended.

```
folder_im_wdows = folder_im_wdows.replace("//","\\")
```

But the most impressive, is that when I try a workaround doing the next

```
folder_im_wdows = folder_im_wdows.replace("//",chr(92))
```

Python does the same...

The original variable is: //xxxxx//xxxx//xxxx//xxxx//xxx//xxxxx
And I want to get -> \xxx\x\x\x

What's happening with replace method?

Comment: It is working; you are confusing the string representation with the string itself. Try `print(folder_im_wdows)` to view the contents.

Comment: Also, are you sure you *need* to convert the paths?

Comment: @Luis B. Salgado Benitez : please accept an answer if your issues are solved.

Answer (score 3):

This is because python's CLI escapes backslashes.

Example from python's CLI:

```
>>> str = "abc//def//fgh"
>>> str.replace("//", "\\")
'abc\\def\\fgh'
>>> print(str.replace("//", "\\"))
abc\def\fgh
>>>
```

Also, you should need to use `\\` and not only `\`, because you need to escape the backslash character, well, I do.

Comment: It's not the CLI; it's the implementation of `str.__repr__`.

Comment: @chepner: I don't understand. `str.__repr__()` -> `"'abc\\\\def\\\\fgh'"`, `print(str)` -> `abc\def\fgh`

Comment: Because the CLI is then calling `str.__repr__` on the *output* of the explicit call to `str.__repr__`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the details

Answer (score 0):

Use os.path for working with path names:

```
import os

os.path.normpath('C:/Users/Bob/My Documents')
```

os.path.abspath would do the job too (it uses os.path.normpath)

Note: requires host to be windows, if that's not the case you can use ntpath.normpath directly

https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

Avoid regexes, replaces and all that. You're going to get it wrong in some subtle way.